# Django: custom method call in API returns false

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm a beginner in Django doing this tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial02/ I however got stuck at the part where they teach you how to use the API (scroll down untill you reach the **playing with the API** part):

```
>>> q = Question.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> q.was_published_recently()
False
```

Here's the complete source code (models.py):

```
from django.db import models
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text


    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

At first I thought that maybe the spaces between the functions aren't enough so I tried to fix it, when that didn't work I copied and pasted the exact code, can somebody please tell me how what went wrong and how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Python version: 3.5

Operating System: Linux Mint Cinnamon

Comment: There is literally nothing wrong here. The method returns False because, presumably, it is false. I can't understand why you would think that spacing would have anything to do with anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you try to print the fields of your `Question` instance.

```
>>> q = Question.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> q.question_text
'here will be the text of your question instance'
>>> q.pub_date
'here will be the date and time of your question instance'
>>> q.was_published_recently()
False
```

This way you can see the date and time the `Question` instance has set, and that should clear up why your method `was_published_recently` returns `True` or `False`.

Comment: when I typed `q.pub_date` this was the output: `datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 13, 19, 37, 44, 22617, tzinfo=<UTC>)` can you please tell me what those numbers after `2018` are for? I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: That is almost 8 days ago. The method `was_published_recently` will only return `True` if the difference between `pub_date` and the current time is less than a day (see the logic in the mentioned method).

Comment: If you change the part `datetime.timedelta(days=1)` in the method to something greater (maybe `days=10`) then the method should return True. This would be just to confirm that the method works as intended.

Comment: Now that I think of it, there was a time where I didn't manage to continue the tutorial for a couple of days, is this something I should fix in `settings.py` or something?

Comment: There is nothing to fix because there is nothing wrong. Everything works as intended. If you create a new question today, its method `was_published_recently` will return `True`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand what you are having troubles with.

Is it that `q.was_published_recently()` should be really returning `true`? Or are you facing some sort of an error?

Try printing out the `pub_date` before the return statement, to verify what that date actually is.

Comment: Yes it should return `true`, I also did try printing `pub_date` using `print()` but it didn't work, can you use the print() function in Django's API?

Comment: Been a while since I worked with Django, but try print(self.pub_date)

Comment: That didn't work either, this was the output: `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`

Comment: Hmm ok, I guess we could try to update the `was_published_recently` function to only  `return self.pub_date`, and check it that way instead.

Comment: Same results, it returned `false`